# Undefined variable in object

Tags: php, pdo

I am querying a database to define variables:

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare( "SELECT user_id
FROM users
  WHERE user_email = :user_email ;" );
$sth->execute( array( ':user_email' => $email_query ) );

$result = $sth->fetch();
```

However, when I try to use the variable in a function, it returns `$result->user_email is undefined`.

```
$this->mp->createAlias( $result->$user_email );
// $this->mp is defined elsewhere
```

Comment: What about $result->user_email ?

Comment: corrected, `$result->user_email` is undefined

Comment: Could you run _var_dump($result);_ and share the result?

Comment: @Fred-ii- response to RPM spotting a typo.

Comment: @alias51 Except the code is now inconsistent with the message. You still have _$result->$user_email_. Is that in your actual code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
user_id,
FROM users
WHERE user_email = :user_email
```

Your SQL is invalid, remove the comma after user_id.

```
SELECT 
user_id
FROM users
WHERE user_email = :user_email
```

It's also best to use the PDOException. (e.g):

```
try {    
   $sth = $this->db->prepare("
      SELECT 
        user_id
      FROM 
        users
      WHERE user_email = :user_email
   ");
   $sth->execute(array(
       ':user_email' => $email_query
   ));
   $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    var_dump($e);
}
```

The reason that $user_email is undefined because you can't access the returned array that way. You need to access it at it's associative index. `fetch()` returns an array, so you need to access it like an array, not an object.

If your're not getting the property from the object, then it is either undefined and you are not aware of it, or your syntax is wrong, or you need to set the fetch type in PDO.
Try this:

```
$this->mp->createAlias( $result['user_email'] );
```

Comment: yes, sorry that was a typo. the question still stands